# SpannableString.setSpan not working?

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to set different colors for

```
            str.append(" ").append(isBlue ? "b" : "p");
            SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(str);
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(isBlue ? R.color.blue: R.color.pink),
                    spannable.length() - 1,
                    spannable.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            miscTextView.setText(spannable);
```

`str` is an instance of `StringBuilder`.
I am expecting the last character of `miscTextView` to be blue if `isBlue` is true, pink otherwise, while the rest of the text stays black.
But it turns out to be that Either case the last character is grey, which really confuses me. 
What did I do wrong?

Edit: I check the color resource xml already.Intellij shows the color on the left of xml code line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `R.color.blue` which returns the `id`. You should instead get the color as follows:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)
```

so it will be:

```
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(isBlue ? getResources().getColor(R.color.blue): getResources().getColor(R.color.pink)),
                    spannable.length() - 1,
                    spannable.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

The reason it is gray is because the value of `R.color.blue` (the `id` value) maybe an integer corresponding to the color gray.

Comment: Marked. I also tried just now but SO didnt let me because it was too soon after the question was posted.